# How do I not display certain parts of the table from my database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pagination, html-table

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OTgG.png

The image above describes my problem, and provides a visual.
As you can see, I just want to reserve or delete the two spaces on the top-right. How can I achieve this?

This is my current code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
        $objDB = mysql_select_db("dbname");
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM album";
        if (!isset($_GET['Page']))  $_GET['Page']='0';
        $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
        $Num_Rows = mysql_num_rows($objQuery);

        $Per_Page = 12;   // Per Page
        $Page = $_GET["Page"];
        if(!$_GET["Page"])
        {
            $Page=1;
        }

        $Prev_Page = $Page-1;
        $Next_Page = $Page+1;

        $Page_Start = (($Per_Page*$Page)-$Per_Page);
        if($Num_Rows<=$Per_Page)
        {
            $Num_Pages =1;
        }
        else if(($Num_Rows % $Per_Page)==0)
        {
            $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page) ;
        }
        else
        {
            $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page)+1;
            $Num_Pages = (int)$Num_Pages;
        }

        $strSQL .=" order  by albumID ASC LIMIT $Page_Start , $Per_Page";
        $objQuery  = mysql_query($strSQL);


        echo"<table border=\"0\"  cellspacing=\"1\" cellpadding=\"1\"><tr>";
        $intRows = 0;
        while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
        {
            echo "<td>"; 
            $intRows++;
    ?>
            <center>
                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnails/<?=$objResult["Picture"];?>" height="190" width="190" /></a><br>
                <?=$objResult["albumName"];?>
                <br>
            </center>
    <?php
            echo"</td>";
            if(($intRows)%4==0)
            {
                echo"</tr>";
            }
        }
        echo"</tr></table>";
    ?>

        <br>
        <?php
        //DELETED PAGINATION CODE for the sake of simplicity in StackOverflow
                ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_close($objConnect);
?>
```

Comment: It looks like you're never opening a `<tr>` except when you create the table.

Comment: What are you looking to put in those slots? Is it another Picture/albumName that you don't get from the database?

Comment: Yeah pretty much, or it can just be spaces for something unrelated. Haven't decided.

Comment: By the way, you're hammering your database unecessarily. In stead of doing "SELECT * FROM album" and then mysql_num_rows(..) you can do "SELECT count(*) FROM album" which simply returns the number of rows in the table and is very efficient. That'll also eliminate the need to query the album table twice like you're doing now.

Comment: Also, using values from $_GET in DB queries is a security risc. I'd recommend only using $_GET to parse arguments into other variables, and at the same time ensuring that they have valid data. For example for variables that can only have numeric values, do: $PageNum = ($_GET['page'] ? intval($_GET['page'] : 0);

Comment: You don't have to specifically run intval() to convert to integer. You can simply declare `$PageNum = max((int)$_GET['page'], 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Your $intRows variable seems to be counting cells, not rows. So you can simply identify the top right cells by their numbers, which should be 2 and 3. Add this to your loop:

```
$cell = 0;
echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1"><tr>';
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
  if($cell % 4 == 0) {
    echo '</tr><tr>';
  }

  if($cell == 2 || $cell == 3) {
    echo '<td>RESERVED</td>';
  } else {
    echo '<td>'.$objResult["albumName"].'</td>';
  }

  $cell++;
}
echo '</tr></table>';
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working :/. Or maybe I'm putting your code in the wrong spot. Can you specify exactly where I should implement this?

Comment: It should go inside the while loop where you're iterating over the DB records. You also have to make sure you increase $intRows at the correct place. Try replacing the contents of the loop with a simplified version to figure out where the problem is.

Comment: I edited my reply to make it more elaborate. See if that works better.

Comment: Yeah that where I thought I should I implement the code, but what I got is just a page that displays the first two images from my database. That's it. Also, your comments on my original post is very insightful. Unfortunately, I'm a newbie programmer. When I replace my code with "SELECT count(*) FROM album", I get errors. And what's an alternative to &_GET then? Can you make a new ANSWER to detail everything you said so far? EDIT: Just so your post from 7min ago, I'll try it out now.

Comment: Nice, it 'kinda works'. There's some kink in your code (it's not showing images), but I can fix that. Can you elaborate more on the count and $_GET?

Comment: You're selecting the entire table just to determine how many rows there are on it ("SELECT * FROM album"). You can achieve exactly the same result with "SELECT count(*) ..." much more efficiently.

Comment: Parsing $_GET is to ensure against SQL injection. For example if you put $Page into the query string somewhere, someone would be able to change the query string by changing the Page parameter in the URL. http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Answer (score 0):

In your loop, you'd need to put in some conditional statement to break from the default behavior.

```
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
    if(($intRows)%4==0)
    {
        echo"<tr>"; // You forgot this.
    }

    echo "<td>";
    $intRows++;
    if ($intRows == 3 || $intRows == 4) : 
?>
    <!-- special cells -->
<?
    else:
?>
    <center>
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnails/<?=$objResult["Picture"];?>" height="190" width="190" /></a><br>
        <?=$objResult["albumName"];?>
        <br>
    </center>
<?php
    endif;

    echo"</td>";
    if(($intRows)%4==0)
    {
        echo"</tr>";
    }
}
// You also need this part:
echo ($intRows %4 > 0 ? "</tr>" : "") . "</table>";
```

Comment: Hmm, sorry bro, it's not working for some reason. Thanks for the effort though.

Comment: I'm extremely interested to know how that would not work. This is a pretty simple conditional. Can you copy your code? Maybe a typo'ed variable or whatev.