# How do I make this only appear on the first page? And how do I separate two cells?

Tags: php, mysql, pagination, html-table, cell

This code pretty much just shows a a table with 16 cells (4 columns and 4 rows). Except on the top right, there are two "RESERVED" cells. This code also paginates.

There's two things I want to fix with this code. Right now the two "RESERVED cells" are the same. Meaning the two cells both say RESERVED. How do I make it so I can change what's inside the two reserved cell. Sorry if this is a little hard to understand.

Also, I want the two reserved cells to only be shown on the first page. Other than the first page, it would just echo a table with 4x4 cells, as if the reserved cells weren't there.

Can anyone please make this possible?

Without further ado, here's the code:

```
        $Page = $_GET["Page"];
        if(!$_GET["Page"])
        {
            $Page=1;
        }

        $Prev_Page = $Page-1;
        $Next_Page = $Page+1;

        $Page_Start = (($Per_Page*$Page)-$Per_Page);
        if($Num_Rows<=$Per_Page)
        {
            $Num_Pages =1;
        }
        else if(($Num_Rows % $Per_Page)==0)
        {
            $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page) ;
        }
        else
        {
            $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page)+1;
            $Num_Pages = (int)$Num_Pages;
        }

        $strSQL .=" order  by GalleryID ASC LIMIT $Page_Start , $Per_Page";
        $objQuery  = mysql_query($strSQL);
$cell = 0;
echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1"><tr>';
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
  if($cell % 4 == 0) {
    echo '</tr><tr>';
  }

  if($cell == 2 || $cell == 3) {
    echo '<td>RESERVED</td>'; **//How do I make it so there are two separate reserve slots,  
  rather than one <td> which controls both cells?** 
  } else {
    echo '<td><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnails/' . $objResult["Picture"] . '" />' .
            $objResult["GalleryName"] . '</td>'; }
  $cell++;
}
echo '</tr></table>';
    ?>

        <br>
view more:
        <?php
        if($Prev_Page)
        {
            echo " <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Prev_Page'>prev</a> ";
        }
            {
                echo "|";
        }
        if($Page!=$Num_Pages)
        {
            echo " <a href ='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Next_Page'>next</a> ";
        }
        ?>


</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_close($objConnect);
?>
```

Comment: Please don't repost. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5373355/how-do-i-not-display-certain-parts-of-the-table-from-my-database/5373408#5373408

Comment: But this isn't a repost. This is an updated version with new problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($cell == 2) {
    echo '<td>RESERVED</td>';
} elseif ($cell == 3) {
    echo '<td>The other cell</td>';
} else {
    echo '<td><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnails/' . $objResult["Picture"] . '" />' .
    $objResult["GalleryName"] . '</td>'; }
    $cell++;
}
```

*Edit*: this was getting a bit frustrating to understand exactly what was happening on your end, so I rewrote this. This is pretty much what your code should look like. If you can't understand the basic conditionals from here, you need to invest more work in understanding fundamentals on your own time, because a lot of this stuff is rudimentary.

```
$Page = max((int)$_GET["Page"], 1);
$Prev_Page = $Page - 1;
$Next_Page = $Page + 1;

$Page_Start = max(0, ($Per_Page * ($Page - 1) - 2));
if ($Page === 1) $Per_Page = $Per_Page - 2;
$Num_Pages = ceil($Num_Rows / $Per_Page);

$strSQL .= "ORDER BY GalleryID ASC LIMIT {$Page_Start},{$Per_Page}";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);

$cell = 0;
$total = mysql_num_rows($objQuery);
?>

<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1">
    <? for ($cell = 0; $cell < $total; ++$cell) : ?>
        <? if ($cell % 4 === 0) : ?>
            <tr>
        <? endif; ?>
        <td>
            <? if ($Page === 1 && $cell === 2) : ?>
                First reserved cell
                <? --$cell; ?>
            <? elseif ($Page === 1 && $cell === 3) : ?>
                Second reserved cell
                <? --$cell; ?>
            <? else: ?>
                <? $objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery); ?>
                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/thumbnails/<?=$objResult["Picture"]; ?>" />
                <?=$objResult["GalleryName"]; ?>
            <? endif; ?>
        </td>
        <? if ($cell % 4 === 3) : ?>
            </tr>
        <? endif; ?>
    <? endfor; ?>
</table>

<br>
view more:
<?php
    if($Prev_Page) {
        echo " <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Prev_Page'>prev</a> ";
        if($Page != $Num_Pages) echo " | ";
    }

    if($Page != $Num_Pages) {
        echo " <a href ='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Next_Page'>next</a> ";
    }
?>


</body>
</html>
<?php
mysql_close($objConnect);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you! Any idea for the pagination part?

Comment: The conditionals change to `if ($cell == 2 && $Page == 1) {` and `} elseif ($cell == 3 && $Page == 1) {`

Comment: Hmm, I entered what you said, in, but then I get my pagination on my site literally stating "view more: if($Prev_Page) { echo " prev "; } { echo "|"; } if($Page!=$Num_Pages) { echo " next "; } ?>". The prev and next are links and take me to 404 errors.

Comment: Please copy and paste your code. It looks like you've removed the opening <?php tag after "view more:".

Comment: Hmm? I didn't remove the opening <?php after view more. This is the complete code.

Comment: Yeah man. I just want to get my site up and running asap, and so I'm picking up little codes here and there, piecing em together with some knowledge of MySQL and PHP (4 days worth of MySQL and a week and a half of php). Although I've learned some of the language, there are so many gaping holes in my knowledge as well. Thing is, I'm not sure if it's worth learning the whole language since I'm only going to be using the low-level of it. sorry for the trouble and thanks for everything!